# Ошибка 403 для загруженных файлов

Tags: php, файлы, сервер, http, post

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой загрузки файлов методом POST - при попытке доступа к файлу выходит ошибка 403.
При этом загруженные через FTP файлы открываются нормально.
Все права доступа у папки и файла стоят, у папки 777, у файла 666.
Код:

```php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Загрузить файл: <input name="file" type="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Загрузить">
    </form>
    <?php
      if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], 'files/' . $file['name']);
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: путь к папке сохранения нормально укажите, абсолютный.

Comment: Вы загрузили файлы через FTP вероятно под одним пользователем, и пользователю, под которым работает веб-сервер, нет доступа к ним, поэтому вы и получаете 403 Forbidden. Также учтите что права надо проверять для всей иерархии, а не только последней директории.

Comment: пользователь тот же, дерево все проверено